# Grouping a field from multiple rows onto one result row in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm trying to write a query against an oracle DB where I need to take one field from five rows and return one row with all five fields on it.  For instance:

```
PK    RANDOM_COLUMN   IMPORTANT_COLUMN
1       Blah          48
2       Blah          02
3       Blah          67
4       Blah          82
5       Blah          99
6       Blah          10
7       Blah          21
```

I want to select from that and get this:

```
RANDOM_COLUMN  IPC1   IPC2   IPC3   IPC4   IPC5
Blah            48     02     67     82     99
Blah            10     21
```

RANDOM_COLUMN is actually multiple columns that will all be containing the same data.  Any idea how I can get the results I'm looking for?

Update:  Removed because it's too specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually pivot the data after using `row_number()` to assign a sequential number to each row.  A bit of additional arithmetic is required:

```
select blah,
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 1 then important_column end) as ipc1,
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 2 then important_column end) as ipc2,
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 3 then important_column end) as ipc3,
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 4 then important_column end) as ipc4,
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 0 then important_column end) as ipc5
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by blah order by pk) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by blah, trunc((seqnum - 1) / 5);
```